# Laravel task scheduling based on a condition

Tags: laravel, events, cron, scheduled-tasks

I need to add a feature in the project I'm working on that, If a data is inserted in the database, let's say an order has been placed and its 'status' field is pending in the database by default. If a user do not change the 'status' field to 'accepted' within 30 minutes, a email will be sent to a specific person reporting that. How can I proceed to this?

Comment: https://www.cubettech.com/blog/how-to-use-cronjobs-with-laravel/ this will help

Comment: Make a single separated PHP script for this(like a micro-service). and run the script per minute from CRON tab.